# How to fix the error "make sure the kernel module is loaded"?

Tags: kernel-modules, iscsi

I am trying to setup a iSCSI envrionment on Xubuntu with [iSCSI Enterprise Target](http://iscsitarget.sourceforge.net/). I choose this impelmentation because I need the *iSCSI redirection* feature.

First, I installed below 2 pacakges:

[image]

Then I tried to start the servie `ietd` and check the status of the service :

sudo service iscsitarget start
sudo service iscsitarget status

It shows the iscsitarget service is exited. It looks strange but I don't know why.
[image]

Since service is not working, I tried to run the `ietd` as foreground with `-f` switch. The `-c` switch is to specify the config file.

`sudo ietd -f -c /etc/iet/ietd.conf`

It shows this error:
[image]

So I guess some kernel module is missing. If so, how can I fix it? I thought the kernel module is already installed with the `iscsitarget-dkms` pacakge.

Comment: Do you find any clue in `/proc/modules` about the module is actually installed?

Comment: @ZumodeVidrio I just checked, there's no clue of `iet` in the `modules` file. But why it mentioned the `proc/devices` file?